# how to auto increment the number to increment by 1 after saving

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button which I want it to increment by one (1) every time I save. It must display on the label. I am struggling to get the correct format into the label so that it will get displayed every time you clicked save.

```
public void versionIncrement()
{
    count = Convert.ToInt32(lblOutput.Text.ToString()) + 1;
    lblOutput.Text = "1000" + count.ToString();
    lblOutput.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: What format do you require?

Comment: it throws the error on the second line

Comment: Could you update your question with details of the error?

Comment: What is the aim of "1000" + count.ToString()? If count is 1, then  it will be 10001? If your intention is 1001 first add integers, then convert to string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int versionNumber = 1000;

public void versionIncrement()
{
    versionNumber++;
    lblOutput.Text = versionNumber.ToString();
    lblOutput.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: do you know how to change text color if you edited a text from resx file, the color only highlights only text changed not the whole text

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. Perhaps you should ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a private attribute into your form to store the value and increment on click event, for smaple:

```
// init in 1000 for sample
private int _outputValue = 1000; 

public void versionIncrement()
{
   _outputValue += 1; // increment 1
   lblOutput.Text = _outputValue.ToString();
   lblOutput.Visible = true;
}
```